# Maximum risk and sparse estimation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, lasso, regularization

On Larry Wasserman's blog, he talks about the "Steep price of sparsity" here:

http://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/the-steep-price-of-sparsity/

In it, he points out that a sparse estimation procedure (one that forces "small" estimates to zero) has infinite maximum risk. In the simple case of estimating a single parameter $\theta$ given a sample of size $n$:

$$\sup_\theta \mathbb{E}_\theta [n(\hat \theta - \theta)^2] \to \infty $$

And more generally, for a non-negative loss function $\ell$ and a vector of parameters $\beta$, we have

$$\sup_\beta \mathbb{E}_\beta [\ell(n^{1/2}(\hat \beta - \beta))] \to \sup_\beta \ell(\beta)$$

Here, the estimates $\hat \beta$ would be generated via a sparse procedure such as the lasso as opposed to ordinary least squares or maximum likelihood.

My question is, how relevant is this problem? More narrowly, what is the reason for the factor $n^{1/2}$ in the second expression? If this factor didn't appear, the problem (if it is in fact a problem) would become much more innocuous.

Comment: This guy has generated a few pathological examples in the book "all of statistics" - This may be in the same vein.  You're being suspicious is very well founded

Comment: you have a typo - which "explains" the n^1/2 - namely it is l(n^1/2(\beta-\hat{\beta})) [then it is consistent with first expression]

Comment: @seanv507 typo is fixed, but that doesn't change the question.

Comment: So I interpret the first statement as saying that the supremum [over all possible parameter values] of the mean square estimation error converges slower than 1/n with sample size n... so the n actually is weakening the statement.